# Wrong Django version returned in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm on a Mac running OS X !0.10 Yosemite.  Default versions of Python & Django are 2.7 & 1.5.  I'm want to set up a virtualenv that has Django 1.8 so I'm doing the following:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages django18env
New python executable in django18env/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in django18env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ source django18env/bin/activate
(django18env)$
```

Then I'm installing Django 1.8

```
(django18env)$ sudo pip install django==1.8
Password:
Downloading/unpacking django==1.8
  Downloading Django-1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB): 6.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
(django18env)$
```

Once that has run I have Django installed under django18env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django

If I look at the __init__.py file in that directory it shows:

from django.utils.version import get_version
VERSION = (1, 8, 0, 'final', 0)

So it certainly looks like the right version is installed in the virtualenv directory.  However, if I use django-admin --version I get:

```
(django18env)$ django-admin version
1.5.4
```

I've also tried starting python in the virtual env and getting the django version that way:

```
(django18env)$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 29 2014, 21:50:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.5.4'
>>>
```

Any ideas on why it still seems to be pointing to 1.5 when 1.8 is installed in the vertualenv?

I've read various other threads on here but can't get the version to point to 1.8

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: When you are in your virtualenv try typing `which python` what do you get?

Comment: Hi, I get:

/Library/WebServer/Documents/vhosts/django/django18env/bin/python

Which is pointing to the version in the virtualenv

Comment: Try invoking the python in the virtualenv directly.

Answer (score 0):

don't use sudo on virtualenv. the point of vitualenv is, to install software not system wide, but verily for that enviroment. but no matter inside a virtualenv or outside it, if you use sudo, it will install software to your system globally.

```
ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem$ virtualenv ipsum
New python executable in ipsum/bin/python2.6
Also creating executable in ipsum/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
#created a virtualenv
ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem$ cd ipsum/
ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ . bin/activate
# will now install package with sudo 
(ipsum)ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ sudo pip install sudokulib # i don't know what it is, just installing.
[sudo] password for ziya: 
.....
Collecting sudokulib
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages # attention to this path!
...
Successfully installed sudokulib-0.6a0
(ipsum)ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sudokulib # import the newly installed module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sudokulib
>>> exit()
(ipsum)ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ deactivate
#deactivating virtualenv and starting default python
ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sudokulib
>>> sudokulib.__version__
'0.6a' #here it is!
>>> exit()
ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ . bin/activate
(ipsum)ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ pip install sudokulib #now installing the same module without sudo
Collecting sudokulib
  Downloading sudokulib-0.6a.tar.gz
    /home/ziya/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum/lib/python2.6/site-packages
.... 
Successfully installed sudokulib-0.6a0
(ipsum)ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/coursera/python/lorem/ipsum$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sudokulib
>>> sudokulib.__version__
'0.6a' #seems ok now :)
>>>
```

Comment: I've tried that.  If I run pip install django from the virtualenv it says that it can find an existing version (the system wide 1.5) and doesn't install it.  If I try pip install django==1.8 then it does add Django version 1.8 to Python's site-packages in the virtualenv but still uses the old 1.5 when I look for the version

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. As I say above, Django 1.8 was being installed in the virtualenv OK but Python wasn't using it. In the vitualenv I started Python and then:

```
>>>import django
>>>django.__file__
```

This showed that Django had been imported from:
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

And when I looked in my .bash_profile there was a line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Not sure how/when this got in there but I commented it out, restarted the shell and I now get Django1.8 in my virtualenv and the older (default) version 1.5 outside the virtualenv.

Thanks for the help and suggestions