# Unable to Import after Pip Install

Tags: python

Ive just installed a package via pip,

```
  Cloning https://github.com/felix001/commontools.git to /tmp/pip-LMwfnO-build
Installing collected packages: commontools
  Running setup.py install for commontools
Successfully installed commontools-1.0
```

When I try to import commontools it doesnt import.
The path looks ok though,

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import sys
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/felix001',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>> 
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ ls -l /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
total 392
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    119  9 Sep  2014 README
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel    238 18 Dec 21:39 commontools-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    207  3 Nov 20:20 easy-install.pth
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel    136  3 Nov 20:20 pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
drwxr-xr-x  60 root  wheel   2040 23 Oct  2014 scapy
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    261 18 Oct  2014 scapy-2.1.0-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel    238 11 Dec 22:18 threader-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel    204 20 Jul 21:49 vboxapi
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    241 20 Jul 21:49 vboxapi-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel    340  3 Nov 20:21 virtualenv-13.1.2.dist-info
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  99421  3 Nov 20:21 virtualenv.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  83209  3 Nov 20:21 virtualenv.pyc
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel    272  3 Nov 20:21 virtualenv_support
```

Here is the package details.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ pip show commontools
---
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: commontools
Version: 1.0
Summary: commontools
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: ====
Author-email: ====
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

EDIT :

The error is shown below when I try to import,

```
MacBook-Pro:~$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

MacBook-Pro:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from commontools import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named commontools
```

EDIT2 :

So i removed all instances of python. I installed a new version using brew. Same Issue.

New Python path ,

```
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Now if I install anything by pip. It works fine. But if I install my own git repos it fails (??). Heres an example of one - https://github.com/felix001/commontools

Heres an example,

```
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ pip -v install netaddr
Collecting netaddr
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/
  1 location(s) to search for versions of netaddr:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/n/netaddr/netaddr-0.3.1.win32.exe#md5=ba0615105ab8193f4115e2a5767a121c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/n/netaddr/netaddr-0.4.win32.exe#md5=77c28e03c14e081b3339118fad7f1bce (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/); unsupported archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/n/netaddr/netaddr-
0.7.x/CHANGELOG (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/); not a file
    Skipping link http://packages.python.org/netaddr/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/rel-0.7.x/CHANGELOG (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/); not a file
    Skipping link https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/); not a file
  Using version 0.7.18 (newest of versions: 0.7.18, 0.7.18, 0.7.18, 0.7.17, 0.7.17, 0.7.17, 0.7.16, 0.7.16, 0.7.16, 0.7.15, 0.7.15, 0.7.15, 0.7.14, 0.7.14, 0.7.14, 0.7.13, 0.7.13, 0.7.13, 0.7.12, 0.7.12, 0.7.11, 0.7.11, 0.7.10, 0.7.10, 0.7.3, 0.7.3, 0.7.2, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6.4, 0.6.4, 0.6.3, 0.6.3, 0.6.2, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5.2, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3.1, 0.3.1)
  Using cached netaddr-0.7.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/n/netaddr/netaddr-0.7.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f18d38b78469bb440560544f5559e649 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/netaddr/)
Installing collected packages: netaddr

Successfully installed netaddr-0.7.18
Cleaning up...
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ python 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netaddr
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ pip -vvv  install git+https://github.com/felix001/commontools
Collecting git+https://github.com/felix001/commontools
  Cloning https://github.com/felix001/commontools to /var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-76GaiR-build
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/felix001/commontools /var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-76GaiR-build
  Running setup.py (path:/var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-76GaiR-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/felix001/commontools
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/commontools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-76GaiR-build has version 1.0, which satisfies requirement commontools==1.0 from git+https://github.com/felix001/commontools
Installing collected packages: commontools
  Running setup.py install for commontools
    Running command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-76GaiR-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-hU9LyU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
    running install
    running build
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating commontools.egg-info
    writing commontools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to commontools.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to commontools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'commontools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'commontools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'commontools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Copying commontools.egg-info to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/commontools-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to '/var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-hU9LyU-record/install-record.txt'
  Removing source in /var/folders/13/780bwzl13p5118ldv4qdqgvw0000gn/T/pip-76GaiR-build
Successfully installed commontools-1.0
Cleaning up...
MacBook-Pro:~ felix001$ python 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import commontools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named commontools
>>>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you use sudo? may be something useful can be found in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958776/wrong-django-version-returned-in-virtualenv/32959224#32959224

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  Is is possible you installed the packege to a different version of python?  I've had lots of problems with pip installing the package to a different version of python (python2 vs python3.4 vs pythono3.5)

Comment: I do but Ive opened each one and checked. Question updated

Comment: perhaps try to install it inside virtual environment? for experimental

Comment: Just trying this. But stil faced the same issue

Comment: @felix001 I tried to install it, and succeed. Need to install simplejson first though. Can you show us the error message when you try to import it?

Comment: It looks as though `pip` is installing the package to a different `site-packages/` directory than the one used by whatever Python executable is currently first in your  shell search path. Try this: `PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH python` and see if you can then `import commontools`.

Comment: Tried this but this failed. ie was still unable to import.

Comment: Can you add the error output when you try to import commontools?

Comment: Added to question under EDIT

Comment: type `which python` on the command line, it will tell use which interpreter is being called. please post that as well

Comment: can you try reinstalling? why is there no actual commontools directory under your site-packages?

Comment: More specifically, egg-info is metadata, where is the actual package? if it's not there, it seems logical the import won't work since there's nothing to import.

Comment: very true, but this is part of my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with `pip`; this is a problem with the [`commontools`](https://github.com/felix001/commontools/blob/master/setup.py) package.

Here is its **`setup.py`**:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="commontools",
    version="1.0",
    author="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    author_email="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    description="commontools",
)
```

It does not even follow the [minimal viable example for packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/minimal.html) or the [basic use](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html?highlight=find_packages#basic-use) for `setuptools`.

**TL;DR:**
It is not including the source files; which is what the `packages` keyword for `setup()` does.